# Tooltwist Stack trace after log in to designer: "com.dinaa.xpc.XpcConfigException: Unknown user type: 'phinza'"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, stack-trace, tooltwist

I am getting this error after I log in and access the ToolTwist designer after deployment:

```
Stack trace:
com.dinaa.xpc.XpcConfigException: Unknown user type: 'phinza'
at com.dinaa.xpc.backend.XpcSecurityImpl.login(XpcSecurityImpl.java:296)
at com.dinaa.xpc.XpcLogin.login(XpcLogin.java:51)
at com.dinaa.xpc.XpcLogin.login(XpcLogin.java:80)
at tooltwist.basic.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:136)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.myrp.util.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:22)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What are the possible errors that could lead to these stack traces and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just missing to include ttsec-standaloneDesigner as projectLayer in your tooltwist.xml. Try to add this line on your tooltwist.xml before the webdesign projectLayer element:

```
<projectLayer>ttsec-standaloneDesigner</projectLayer>
```

You should see something like this

```
    <projectLayer>myrp_t</projectLayer>
    <projectLayer>ttsec-standaloneDesigner</projectLayer>
    <projectLayer>webdesign</projectLayer>
```

Comment: Thanks Laurence! This helped me a lot! =)

Answer (score 2):

***ttsec-standaloneDesigner*** is only one of the plugin that you can use. See **["Configuring Security Plugins"](https://github.com/tooltwist/documentation/wiki/Configuring-security-plugins)** for other available plugins and complete documentation about this.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation @ryacii ! =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ToolTwist in Eclipse, check that you have the ttsec-standalone project installed alongside tooltwist, ttStd and ttWbd, so the Designer can get access to it's config files.